# WSL won't switch to WSL2, ignores commands

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server-2019

I'm running a preview version of Windows Server 2019, version 2004, build 20262.1000

I've installed WSL, including a Ubuntu distro. The `wsl --help` command perfectly lists the `--set-default-version <Version>` and `--set-version <Distro> <Version>` commands.

However, when I execute any of these commands with `<Version>` set to 2, it seems to completely ignore the command and just print the help file. It doesn't even say `Invalid command line option:`, just prints help.

It seems to be completely aware of the command, throwing errors when specifying other versions like 1, 3, 4, etc. But 2 seems to do absolutely nothing.

Example:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl -l -v
  NAME      STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu    Stopped         1
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
No such interface supported
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 4
A version number could not be parsed.
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]

Arguments for running Linux binaries:

    If no command line is provided, wsl.exe launches the default shell.

    --exec, -e <CommandLine>
        Execute the specified command without using the default Linux shell.

    --
        Pass the remaining command line as is.

Options:
... [rest of help file] ...
```

Same thing for `--set-default-version`:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> wsl --set-default-version 2
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Usage: wsl.exe [Argument] [Options...] [CommandLine]

Arguments for running Linux binaries:
...
```

How can I start using WSL2 on my Windows Server installation?

Comment: which is the windows version you have installed? WSL 2 is only available in the 2004 update or greater.

Comment: You do understand you don’t actually have 2004 installed right? 20262 Is 21H1 which is an Insider Preview build.  You do understand setting the version to anything other than 1 or 2 isn’t supposed to work right?  Please edit your question to indicate what Windows features you have installed

Comment: @BANJOSA as stated in the first line , my system reports 2004, build 20262. It's the latest available preview build for Windows Server.
Ramhound I guess I don't understand then. Why does Windows say it's version 2004, but you're telling me this build number is not version 2004?

Comment: @René - Microsoft doesn’t update the version information until it’s closer to release but I can promise you that your not running 2004 based on that build number

Comment: @Ramhound what the hell, that's so confusing. It LITERALLY says "Version: 2004" and then that build number after it. So that version number is completely meaningless? What's the point to this number even?

Comment: @Ramhound that's not what I meant with my comment. I was simply referring to the fact that it's very weird that Windows literally says it's version 2004 in "About", but that it also apparely means nothing at all, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @René - You are using an Insider Preview build in a Beta release channel.  Microsoft doesn’t change the release version until much closer to the actual release of the feature update.  I used ChangeWindows.org to determine you are running 21H1 instead of 2004.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to update your windows build to 202011 or higher. Try joining the insiders program to get this build and it will work fine after an update.